# Define a class is not working globally but locally it is

Tags: css, wordpress

When I define a code for a class within the custom CSS of a post this is working however if I define the same code globally under my theme options-> Custom CSS this is not working.

```
.learndash-wrapper .ld-table-list a.ld-table-list-item-preview {
    color: #13fff8;
}.
```

Therefore I have to go post by post adding this code to get the proper font color... and I would like to have it globally working.

Any idea why this happened?

Comment: Have you deployed your code on any server?

Answer (score 3):

First, check whether you have a typo or not. After verifying that you have entered class name properly. You can try out as,

```
.your-class-name{
  color : #ffffff !important;
}
```

**!important** has the superpower to override previous CSS class and it's properties.

There are guidelines and defined the precedence of different CSS stylings. 
Checkout,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Ask in the comment if required a more specific answer.

Comment: Using `!important;` is generally seen as _lazy_ and _bad practice_. [This article](https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/) sums up well as to why that is.

Comment: @vitinx You have to send your HTML code so we easily get understand to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the order of the css files loaded. If you have declared multiple css for same element latest class css will be applied. Along with that check the specificity of the css selectors. The selector with higher specificity will be affect the style.